# HMAC in Javascript does not match HMAC in Python because of quotes

Tags: javascript, python, hmac

I have a client in JavaScript that carries out hmac as follows:

```
generateHMAC: function (payload) {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  let hmacpsk = app.get('secret_key');
  const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', hmacpsk).update(JSON.stringify(payload)).digest('hex');
  resolve(hmac);
})
```

},

The payload is as follows:

```
{"patients":[{"id":96,"position":[40.475268,-3.6957545],"area_id":38,"visit":30}],"doctors":[{"id":18,"position":[40.45993,-3.686387],"area_id":38,"start_timestamp":"2022-12-11T23:00:00.000Z","visit":240}],"areas":[{"area_id":38,"transport":"walking"}]}
```

When performing JSON.stringify(payload) it appears like this:

```
"{\"patients\":[{\"id\":96,\"position\":[40.475268,-3.6957545],\"area_id\":38,\"visit\":30}],\"doctors\":[{\"id\":18,\"position\":[40.45993,-3.686387],\"area_id\":38,\"start_timestamp\":\"2022-12-11T23:00:00.000Z\",\"visit\":240}],\"areas\":[{\"area_id\":38,\"transport\":\"walking\"}]}"
```

and the hash is the following:

```
84257087ef9cf31f376a8b39e36ac0d97de91d53c8e373cb1e936a51ca5664a2
```

On the Python server side, I have the following code:

```
#get the body of the request
values = json.loads(request.get_data(as_text=True))
#generate new hmac
clave=hmac.new(b"secret_key", bytes(str(values), 'utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
print("The new key is:")
print (clave)
```

The aspect of str(values) is as follows:

```
'{\'patients\':[{\'id\':96,\'position\':[40.475268,-3.6957545],\'area_id\':38,\'visit\':30}],\'doctors\':[{\'id\':18,\'position\':[40.45993,-3.686387],\'area_id\':38,\'start_timestamp\':\'2022-12-11T23:00:00.000Z\',\'visit\':240}],\'areas\':[{\'area_id\':38,\'transport\':\'walking\'}]}'
```

And the hash I get is the following:

```
a156bdf7a0c05443337bbf02ebe555b9004d275089c6bc5dae2ebff64d01f170
```

That as you can see differs from the one in the client. Do you know what is the problem? Maybe is related to quotes? I tried replacing quotes but the same problem arises.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that `str(values)` does not produce JSON.  If you want the HMAC of the JSON, then you need to encode `json.dumps`, not `str(values)`.

Comment: Still not working. I am using the following `values = json.dumps(OrderedDict(json.loads(request.get_data())))` and after processing this `clave=hmac.new(b"secret_key", bytes(values, "utf-8"), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()`, it produces the following hash:  `'b954107590a360a3c390009d6a6a9e1301293752c37668d3a1e2fb28b594db4a'`. If a take ``values`` as a raw string and execute the same function the hash is different. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm wondering about your Javascript code.  Is your function actually receiving a Javascript object, or are you receiving a string that has already been JSON encoded?  I'm wondering if you are re-encoding something that's already encoded.  Also, the Python JSON encoder adds spaces after the commas, which `json_stringify` does not, so the digest is not going to be the same.  Why do you care about this?

Comment: @TimRoberts, you were right. It was a problem with spaces, not possible to see with my eyes but yes when including `assert`. Thank you :)